# Iterate through a loop, add extra line every 4 iterations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, loops

I've got the following loop:

```
<% @count = 0%>
<%@cards.each do |p|%>
<li class="span3">
   <div class="thumbnail">
      <a href="#"><img src=<%= p["url"] %> alt=""></a>
   </div>
   <div class="caption">
      <h4> <%= p["categories"] %> </h4>
      <p>
         <%= p["desc"] %>
      </p>
   </div>
</li>
<%@count++%>
<% if @count == 4 %>
</ul>
</div><!-- /Slide1 -->
<div class="item">
<ul class="thumbnails">
<% @count = 0%>
<%end%>
<%end%>
```

I'm trying to show the extra bit of html on every fourth iteration, but I just keep getting an error:

`#<NoMethodError: undefined method '+@' for nil:NilClass`

Comment: Could you post the error you're getting?

Comment: The Ruby syntax to increment is not `@count ++` but `@count += 1`

Comment: You Ruby guys don't have modulus operator?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You should use `.each_with_index`:

```
<% @cards.each_with_index do |p, i| %>

    # your stuff

    <% if ((i+1) % 4) == 0 %>

      # your stuff for every 4th element

    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

---

Also, **a little advice**: You should not defined instance variables (starting with `@`) in your views. They are usually set in your Controller, then shared to your view (and partials used in your view).

If one day you end up setting a variable `@something = 12` inside a view, then it should be replaced with a simple local variable `something = 12` (and eventually pass it to your partials if they need it).

Answer (score 0):

Ruby doesn't have ++ increment operator. so please change `<%@count++%>` to `<% @count += 1 %>` and the error will go away. however, like everyone else says, using each_with_index will be a good idea